# flatMap a list of strings to a list of integers

Tags: scala

Given a list s strings, e.g.:

```
val list = List("1", "2")
```

I can convert them to a list of Integers easily with:

```
list.map(_.toInt)
```

However, if the list of strings contains non-integers, is there a way to easily fillter them out in Scala?

For example:

```
val list = List("1", "2", "output")
```

Using the above `map(_.toInt)` will have an exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "output"

I trying using `flatMap`, but it won't compile:

> :13: error: type mismatch;
>      found   : Int
>      required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Try` is good, but sometimes you want to avoid exceptions.

```
List("4","4g5","77").collect{case x if x.forall(_.isDigit) => x.toInt} 
//res0: List[Int] = List(4, 77)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution:

```
val list: List[Char] = List('1', 'a', '2') 
list.filter(_.isDigit).map(_.asDigit.toInt)
```

Comment: OP was asking about strings instead of chars, but I think this will work `list.filter(_.forall(_.isDigit)).map(_.toInt)`